# Convert a specific cell to VALUE across multiple sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to convert the same cell (say A1), from formula to value on multiple tabs using a script?

My specific case is that I've done a custom function called =sheetname() so that I can have a cell having the sheet name..., then I'm using a tool to create a large tab collection from a template, in a spreadsheet where each tab has an incrementing ID (S23 001, S23 002, S23 003, and so on...), and there is a cell in each of these tab containing the sheetname function.

The problem is that the function (=sheetname()) has a certain delay of operation, and since I'm getting data on another spreadsheet from these sheets using a vlookup function having these cells for search key, the fact that the cells having the sheet names are formulas instead of values, it seems to slow down the hole system.

This is why I'd like to be able to to have all these cells across all the sheets to be values (say the cell A1 on all the sheets), and the most practical way would be to have a script the does that in one click.

Can you help?
Thank you!

I tried nothing of that sort since I don't know how to make a script that does that.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample spreadsheet with dummy values, and also your current output and expected output so that we can further help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
function samecellvalueinallsheet(rga1="A1") {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sh => sh.getRange(rga1).setValue(sh.getName());
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```